# Update array values based on multiple conditions with other arrays having all the same dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array `A` for which I'd like to set `NaN` values based on some conditions with 4 other arrays, each having the same dimensions than A.

Here's an example:

```py
import numpy as np

A = 5*np.ones((4,4))

B = np.zeros((4,4))
C = np.zeros((4,4))
D = np.zeros((4,4))
E = np.zeros((4,4))

B[0,0] = -6
C[0,-1] = 6
D[-1,0] = -6
E[-1,-1] = 6

# This is what I'm trying to do, if possible in one shot:
A[(A-B>10 or A-C<0 or A-D>10 or A-E<0)]=np.nan # -> error 1
A[(A-B>10 | A-C<0 | A-D>10 | A-E<0)]=np.nan # -> error 2

np.where(A-B>10 or A-C<0 or A-D>10 or A-E<0,np.nan,A) # -> error 1
np.where(A-B>10 | A-C<0 | A-D>10 | A-E<0,np.nan,A)    # -> error 2
```

*(my arrays are actually much more complex, don't focus on the values here, they only serve as an example)*

but this gives me error 1:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

or error 2:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I also tried:

```py
np.logical_and(A-B>10, A-C<0, A-D>10, A-E<0)
```

which gives:

```py
np.logical_and(A-B>10, A-C<0, A-D>10, A-E<0)

ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

I know I can convert each of the 4 boolean array to binary values and then taking the average and converting that back to boolean but that would not be memory efficient.

All advice on how I can use several conditions to update some values to `NaN` of my first array is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it using parentheses, as in 'if' statements for example:

```
A[(A-B>10) | (A-C<0) | (A-D>10) | (A-E<0)] = np.nan
```

or

```
np.where((A-B>10) | (A-C<0) | (A-D>10) | (A-E<0), np.nan, A)
```

both resulting in:

```
>>> A

array([[nan,  5.,  5., nan],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [nan,  5.,  5., nan]])
```